# Prevent .net program from writing to disk

Tags: .net, runtime

How do I prevent my .net (C#) program from ever writing to disk?

Edit: There's a  [FileIOPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionattribute.aspx) for anyone curious. This [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/UB_CAS_NET.aspx) also shows a way.

Comment: Technically, you can't. Someone could inject IL or a native DLL to cause writes to disk. You could use Sandboxie though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use caspol to ensure that the exe is not executed with "full trust", and limit the trust excluding that permission (`FileIOPermission`). However, if the exe is not *designed and tested* to run without full trust, it could completely fail to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You can run it with an account that is not authorized to write to disk.

Comment: You can have a Windows account that's not authorized to write to disk at all? How does it write its own settings?